# Linear combination of vectors that yields two orthonormal vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, orthonormal

Given two sets of linearly independent vectors $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}, \{w_1, w_2, w_3\}$ with each vector $ \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$, I am trying to find the linear combination with coefficients $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
\begin{align}
r_1 &= \alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha_2 v_2 + \alpha_3 v_3,\\
r_2 &= \alpha_1 w_1 + \alpha_2 w_2 + \alpha_3 w_3,\\
\end{align}
$$
yields orthonormal vectors $r_1, r_2 \in\mathbb{R}^{3}$, i.e.
$$
\lVert r_1 \lVert^2 = r_1^\top r_1 = 1,\qquad \lVert r_2 \lVert^2 = r_2^\top r_2 = 1,\qquad r_1^\top r_2 = 0.
$$

This problem can also be formulated as finding the vector $\alpha = (\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3)^\top$ satisfying
$$
\begin{align}
\alpha^\top V^\top V\alpha = 1,\\
\alpha^\top W^\top W\alpha = 1,\\
\alpha^\top V^\top W\alpha = 0,\\
\end{align}
$$
where
$$
V = \begin{bmatrix}
\vert & \vert & \vert\\
v_1 & v_2 & v_3\\
\vert & \vert & \vert\\
\end{bmatrix}, \qquad 
%
W = \begin{bmatrix}
\vert & \vert & \vert\\
w_1 & w_2 & w_3\\
\vert & \vert & \vert\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Does a solution to this problem exist? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Go back to the first sentence, please. You need to do some serious revising.

Comment: Do you mean two sets of three linearly independent vectors? You can't have six linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: A solution may exist, or it may not exist depending on the choice of the six vectors.

Comment: @TedShifrin my bad, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @CyclotomicField thank you for noting this. I've corrected it now. I mean two sets of three linearly independent vectors.

Comment: @Erinishighclass Please, can you elaborate that point?

Comment: In almost all cases there will be a solution, however, if you choose $v_1, v_2, v_3$ and $w_1, w_2, w_3$ such that they represent the axes of two coordinate frames (any two coordinate frames are related by a rotation matrix which is characterized by an axis and an angle of rotation); if the angle of rotation of this rotation matrix relating the two coordinate frames is not $90^\circ$ then it is impossible to satisfy orthogonality, and there will be no solution.   I have written a small program with arbitrary vectors, and there was more than one solution for $(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3)$

Comment: @Erinishighclass thank you for the explanation and help. I see your point regarding what happens if the vectors form the axes of two coordinate frames. After doing a simple numerical exploration that issue seems to be rare (I could not make it happen). It also makes sense that more than one solution exist. Concretely if $\alpha^{*}$ solves the system then $-\alpha^{*}$ is also a solution. However, I don't know if more than two real solutions exist.

Comment: Yeah.  I don't know that either.  In my small simultation, I got 4 solutions, with 2 solutions being the negative of the other two.

Comment: Obviously, if $W=V$ (or the columns are a permutation), there is no solution. What happens if you fix $V$ and wiggle slightly to get $W$?